# python strip function on special characters

Tags: python

i have a file like the one below. I am trying to read it, remove the slashes. The reading works file but when i remove slashes `\`

```
module pe (c_imm_z03a, c_lt_func_z40a, c_or_z43a, c_opr1_z43a, 
    c_oprk_z43a, c_oprl_z43a, c_orm_z43a, c_wtn_z404a, 
    c_wtx_z404a, \imm_pkt_z43a[0] , \imm_pkt_z43a[1] , ldimm_z402b_b, 
    lt_anden_z43a, \lt_imm_z43a_b[0] , \lt_imm_z43a_b[1] , 
    \lt_imm_z43a_b[2] , \lt_imm_z43a_b[3] , \lt_imm_z43a_b[4] , 
    \lt_imm_z43a_b[5] , \lt_imm_z43a_b[6] , \lt_imm_z43a_b[7] , 
    \lt_imm_z43a_b[8] , \lt_imm_z43a_b[9] , \lt_imm_z43a_b[10] ,


lines=f.readlines()
for line in lines:
  if "\\" in line:
    print line.strip("\\")
```

This doesnt get me what i want, and i am not sure why not. How do i fix it? Help is appreciated !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str.strip()` removes characters from the *start and end* of a string *only*. Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

> Return a copy of the string with the **leading and trailing** characters removed.

Emphasis mine.

To remove slashes *throughout* a line, use [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
print line.replace("\\", '')
```

or use [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) for a faster approach to delete characters:

```
print line.translate(None, '\\')
```

Comment: Thanks, in what situations would I use replace over translate if translate is faster?

Comment: @Illusionist: `str.replace()` lets you substitute multi-character source characters with a multi-character target. `str.translate()` can only handle single characters.